# Image icon error ocuring while uploading to appstore?

Tags: ios

An error like in the below image is showing when i try to upload it to app store

[image: Error]

While uploading to app store missing 120x120 image icon error is occuring. I have already added the details in json file.But it still showing the error.There is no json format error.

This below one is my Json file

```
{  
   "images":[  
      {  
         "size":"20x20",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-20x20@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"20x20",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-20x20@3x.png",
         "scale":"3x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"29x29",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-29x29@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"29x29",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-29x29@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"29x29",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-29x29@3x.png",
         "scale":"3x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"40x40",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-40x40@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"40x40",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-40x40@3x.png",
         "scale":"3x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"57x57",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-57x57@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"57x57",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-57x57@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"60x60",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-60x60@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"60x60",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-60x60@3x.png",
         "scale":"3x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"20x20",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-20x20@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"20x20",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-20x20@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"29x29",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-29x29@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"29x29",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-29x29@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"40x40",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-40x40@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"40x40",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-40x40@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"50x50",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-Small-50x50@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"50x50",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-Small-50x50@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"72x72",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-72x72@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"72x72",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-72x72@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"76x76",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-76x76@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"76x76",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-76x76@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"83.5x83.5",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"1024x1024",
         "idiom":"ios-marketing",
         "filename":"app icon_1024x1024-1.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"40x40",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-40x40@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"60x60",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-60x60@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"76x76",
         "idiom":"iphone",
         "filename":"Icon-App-76x76@1x.png",
         "scale":"1x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"76x76",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-76x76@3x.png",
         "scale":"3x"
      },
      {  
         "size":"60x60",
         "idiom":"ipad",
         "filename":"Icon-App-60x60@2x.png",
         "scale":"2x"
      }
   ],
   "info":{  
      "version":1,
      "author":"xcode"
   }
}
```

I tried a lot,but i was not able to find a solution for the issue.Please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Icon-App-60x60@2x.png check the dimension assets. it's 60x60 only

Comment: ya, it's dimension is 60X60 and scale is 2X, so its 120X120

Comment: dimension should  be 120